# Specify default entityManager in global request parameter with Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have 2 entityManager configured and working correctly (all mappings loaded correctly etc), giving me ability to work with 2 databases.

In a similar manner to which the standard Doctrine Command tasks allow either an --em or --connection arguments, I would like to effectively specify the EntityManager and hence the DB that is used.

I have done the obvious and hacky thing of switching the container references in the Command:

```
if ($input->getOption('background')) {
  $this->container->set('doctrine.orm.entity_manager', $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.background_entity_manager'));
}
```

This works for the first x number of db queries (is a long-running command) but when the Doctrine performs a reconnect, the default EntityManager appears to be used and the other db connected to:

```
2016-04-07T11:27:47.792427Z  783 Connect    root@10.20.1.1 on partridge_background using TCP/IP
2016-04-07T11:27:47.802813Z  783 Query  SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.last_completion AS last_completion_3, t0.last_run AS last_run_4, t0.bookie_id AS bookie_id_5 FROM feeds t0 WHERE t0.name = 'CORAL_OPENBET' LIMIT 1
2016-04-07T11:27:47.823585Z  783 Query  SELECT c0_.id AS id_0, c0_.name AS name_1, c0_.canonicalised_name AS canonicalised_name_2, c0_.matchable_name AS matchable_name_3, c0_.display_order AS display_order_4, c0_.filtered AS filtered_5, c0_.name_alias AS name_alias_6, c0_.created_at AS created_at_7, c0_.updated_at AS updated_at_8, m1_.id AS id_9, m1_.domain_id AS domain_id_10, m1_.feed_id AS feed_id_11, m1_.feed_element_id AS feed_element_id_12, m1_.feed_request_url AS feed_request_url_13, m1_.feed_last_updated AS feed_last_updated_14, c0_.category2_id AS category2_id_15, m1_.domain_id AS domain_id_16 FROM category3 c2_, category3 c0_ INNER JOIN metacategory3 m1_ ON c0_.id = m1_.domain_id WHERE c0_.filtered = 0
2016-04-07T11:27:49.057129Z  784 Connect    root@10.20.1.1 on partridge using TCP/IP
2016-04-07T11:27:49.060680Z  784 Query  SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.canonicalised_name AS canonicalised_name_3, t0.matchable_name AS matchable_name_4, t0.display_order AS display_order_5, t0.filtered AS filtered_6, t0.name_alias AS name_alias_7, t0.created_at AS created_at_8, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_9, t0.category2_id AS category2_id_10 FROM category3 t0 WHERE t0.id = 48
2016-04-07T11:27:49.065852Z  784 Query  SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.domain_id AS domain_id_2, t0.feed_id AS feed_id_3, t0.feed_element_id AS feed_element_id_4, t0.feed_request_url AS feed_request_url_5, t0.feed_last_updated AS feed_last_updated_6, t0.domain_id AS domain_id_7 FROM metacategory3 t0 WHERE t0.domain_id = 48
```

Doing this EntityManager switching so relatively late in the framework lifecycle is obviously the wrong approach. What i would like is some kind of Symfony bootstrap event listener that could change the default EntityManager based on the request (in this case and ArgvInput arguments but would be nice if could listen for arguments on any type of Request).

I'm thinking some kind of dynamic config manipulation at runtime?

Comment: ``This works for the first x number of db queries (is a long-running command) but when the Doctrine performs a reconnect`` - reconsider if using Doctrine in long-running command is really necessary. PHP wasn't designed to do such things and - later or earlier - you'll encounter on memory leaks. More information on your application logic will be helpful. Especially how do you flush your UoW?

Comment: This command runs well with the default EM and despite the overhead of an ORM performs well enough. Flushes are done intermittently, as recommended in the docs

Comment: How do you get an entity manager instance? Posting some relate code would be helpful.

Comment: Am on mobile ATM. All calls are made through Doctrine manager, I.e. $container->get('Doctrine.ORM.entity_manager')->getRepositoryXXXX

Comment: This will retrieve the default EM obvs but adding switches at all points of EM retrieval is not an option

Comment: Have you tried to set up an alias instead of re-creating definition?

Comment: I literally need the instance referred to by the doctrine.ORM.entity_manager container key to be altered early in the symfony lifecycle.

Comment: Okay, in the other words - I mean your "hack" but try using ``setAlias`` instead of pure ``set``.

Answer (score 0):

Giving it some thought and a bit of research (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1437) leads me to the conclusion that it is not possible to alter the services the container can reasonably return at run time due it's "compiled" nature. The solution it seems is to create a new environment with its own configs and use the --env switch when calling my Command.